# Why this delimiter is not working as it should?

Tags: java, string, delimiter

ok, so we are supposed to make a program that simply reads proper input for a date in the format of mm/dd/yyyy. All I  have learned so far are if-else statements, touched on enum's a bit, string processing, switch statements, and that's pretty much it. I figured the best way to go about this was to use a delimiter of / to capture each month day and year input separately, but when I run  what you see below, the program literally just stops after you enter, say 5/16/1985......to clarify the program is actually still running, but nothing happens (i.e. the expected string process and the output of their values). Once I type in the date, it just does nothing, and I was wondering why? Did the delimiter not work? Am I thinking of using a delimiter in the wrong way? Its driving me crazy lol, any advice would be nice!

Also wanted to add that I tried this both with creating strings after the delimiter (as you see below) and with just trying to capture INT values using nextInt.....still does the same thing and nothing happens after the initial date entry....

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

keyboard.useDelimiter("/");

String month = keyboard.next();
String day = keyboard.next();
String year = keyboard.next();

int monthi = Integer.parseInt(month);
int dayi = Integer.parseInt(day);
int yeari = Integer.parseInt(year);

System.out.println(monthi);
System.out.println(dayi);
System.out.println(yeari);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your delimiter to also include newline:

```
keyboard.useDelimiter("[/\n]");
```

this way your last `.next()` call will have something to parse for.  You can also use `keyboard.hasNext()` to determine if there is anything left to parse (if not you may want to handle that case, as a non-valid date was entered).

The reason your code runs forever in its current state, is you are using 3 `next()` calls, but only providing 2 `\`'s, your program would terminate when you added a 3rd `\` the way it used to be, but by adding newline to the list of things to delimit (the `\n` character) the last `next()` call will pull whats between the last slash and the newline.

Comment: trying that now.... darn no luck, same thing, it still just does nothing, eclipse shows the program is still running, but the expected output still not occuring.....

Comment: @user2035824 I edited my answer and tested it, should work now.

Comment: @ Kevin D. Yup that (almost) did it! I did however get an error when it attempted to parse the INT value from year, because it had the whitespace after it(at least I assumed that was the issue), so I modified what you suggested to include year.trim(), then it worked like a charm! Thank you for pointing me in the right direction, now hopefully all my if- else statements will work for leap year and 30 or 31 days!